# Creating cloud database and use in Android

Tags: android, database

I want to create a mockup of a bank database(big data on the cloud), that is have a person table, cards table, balance table etc etc

What is the best way to do this ? 
I tried using FireBase, but It seems to have a different use :)

Thank you

Comment: You can search for another MBAAS if you don't like Firebase. For instance, Parse: https://www.parse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP can be a better option if your app having large number of data on server side .
You can use REST API too for some specific senario.

FireBase is not suiting your requirment as that used for instant messaging.